# A proper term for arguments of GROUP BY and aggregate functions, like SUM()

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate, terminology

The answer I couldn't find anywhere, what is a term for columns listed in GROUP BY clause? And in opposite, what is a name for columns to which aggregate functions applied?

Comment: in group by you can have either keys (columns) or aggregate functions so it means group by expression meaning it can involve both

Comment: Just for reference, there doesn't seem to be any more specific term used in common [relational algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Aggregation) either. So, they're "columns" :-)

Comment: Words matter. +1 for that.

Comment: <group by clause> ::=
GROUP BY [ <set quantifier> ] <grouping element list>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would refer to them as "group by keys" or aggregation keys.

I find that documentation in different databases is not consistent, so there might be some flexibility.  "group by element" or "group by expression" both convey the idea, unambiguously.

There is not a special name for the arguments of aggregation functions.  These can be any expressions, including "group by keys".